# android location manager wrong coordinates for different country

Tags: android

I have made an android app using android services location manager .In which I am using network based location manage to fetch location. App is running good in India and it is giving correct location, but when some of friends outside India (like USA, UK) run this app ,I get wrong coordinate thats points to china or kazakistan. I am not able to understand this problem.If any one has come across this issue , Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

CODE IS BELOW :

```
//changes - start for fused location
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
//import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
//changes end for fused location with one comment above library

public class LocationService extends Service
{
    //public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public MyLocationListener listener;
    public Location previousBestLocation = null;
    public String userMobile;

    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }


   public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flag, int startId)
    {
        try {
            if (isOnline()) {
                try {
                    int time = 2 * 60 * 1000;
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    listener = new MyLocationListener();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, time, 0, listener);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, 0, listener);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String error = e.getMessage();
                }
            }
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        } catch (Exception e){
            stopService(new Intent(LocationService.this,LocationService.class));
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    /** Checks whether two providers are the same */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        super.onDestroy();
        //Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }

    public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {

                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return t;
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            int timeOut = 0;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
                String responseString = null;
                if(isOnline()) {
                ///do something....
                }
                return responseString;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)
        {
            if(isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
                Double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                Double longitude = loc.getLongitude();

                String mainUrl = "www.xyz.com";
                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();

                float invAccuracy = loc.getAccuracy();
                float accuracy = 0;
                if(invAccuracy > 0.0){
                    accuracy = 100 - invAccuracy;
                }

                builder.scheme("http")
                        .authority(mainUrl)
                        .appendQueryParameter("acc",Float.toString(accuracy))
                        .appendQueryParameter("lt",latitude.toString())
                        .appendQueryParameter("ln",longitude.toString());
                String urlStr = builder.build().toString();
                new RequestTask().execute(urlStr);
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }


        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: _I get wrong coordinate_ what do you mean by this? co-ordinates are different and unique for every other country..

Comment: Wrong coordinate means coordinate which I am getting through app is, belong to different country. like friend is in USA so its coordinate should belong to USA only but it belongs to kazakistan.